# 'QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running' on quit

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to find a way to quit my app properly. When I exit, I get an error saying `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`. I have a thread for feeding output to a `QTextBrowser`. What should be the proper way to exit? Here's what I've got:

```
class LogReceiver(QtCore.QObject):
    mysignal = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, queue, *args, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            text = self.queue.get()
            self.mysignal.emit(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    thread = QtCore.QThread()
    my_receiver = MyReceiver(queue)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    my_receiver.mysignal.connect(window.append_text)
    my_receiver.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(my_receiver.run)
    thread.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Should `thread` somehow be terminated upon exit? Note that `self.queue.get()` blocks and waits for text.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to re-structure the while loop so that it doesn't block uncondtionally.

You can do this with a simple flag and a timeout:

```
    def run(self):
        self.active = True
        while self.active:
            try:
                text = self.queue.get(timeout=1.0)
                self.mysignal.emit(text)
            except Empty:
                continue
```

So now the queue won't block indefinitely, and the flag will be checked once a second to see if the loop should be exited.

**EDIT**:

Here's a working example based on your code:

```
import sys
from queue import Queue, Empty
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class LogReceiver(QtCore.QObject):
    mysignal = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, queue, *args, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        self.active = True
        while self.active:
            try:
                text = self.queue.get(timeout=1.0)
                self.mysignal.emit('text')
            except Empty:
                continue
        print('finished')

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.receiver = LogReceiver(self.queue)
        self.receiver.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.receiver.run)
        self.thread.start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print('close')
        self.receiver.active = False
        self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Using prajmus's second solution along with the argument `timeout=1.0`, it'd get stuck at `thread.wait()` though.

Comment: @Kate. I don't think any of those solutions are going to work, because they try to operate on the thread after the main event-loop has terminated. I've added a working example to my answer to show how my solution should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
# previous code here
thread.start()
app.exec_()

thread.terminate()
thread.wait()
sys.exit(0)
```

Basically when `exec_()` finishes (`QApplication` is closed ex. by closing the window) you force the `thread` to terminate and `wait()` for it to cleanup. If your thread has an event loop you can call `quit()` instead of `terminate()`. `terminate()` is generally not a good idea see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898636/how-can-i-terminate-a-qthread).

The more desirable approach would be to put a flag in `run()` method ex.

```
while !flag:
    do stuff
```

and change main to:

```
app.exec_()
flag = True
thread.wait()
sys.exit(0)
```

Where `flag` is a global variable. `QThread` terminates itself when `run()` method finishes.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I can run `thread.wait()` because the thread is blocking. I've updated my question with how it blocks.

Comment: The way I understand the second solution (with flag) is that `run()` needs to reach the while condition in order for the loop to break. If `text = self.queue.get()` is already blocking when `flag = True` is set, the thread would still be blocked indefinitely.

Comment: @Kate yes you're right, sorry I typed faster than I thought :)

Comment: @Kate can you do it nonblocking way? like while flag: while queue is not empty get text and emit signal. (second while inside the one you already have)